# representation of verilog variable in double IEEE

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to check what is the IEEE 754 equivalent of any floating point number. I tried checking on modelsim and EDA playground. However the results I get are different from the expected.
e.g I tried giving a value a = 2e-309

actual number
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

expected number 0000000000000001011100000010101011100100110100011111101101011101

I am trying to do $display("a=%b",a);

This is my code and testcase snippet

```
module fp_check
  ( input real a,
   output real c);

  assign c = a/6;

endmodule

module tb_fp_check;
  real a;
  real c;

  initial
    begin
      a = 2e-309;
      #5  $display("a=%b, c=%f", a,c);
    end


  fp_check fp (.a(a), .c(c));
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$display` is converting a real number to a integral value to be displayed in binary. If you are looking for the actual bit pattern that represents the real number, use `$realtobits(a)`.